# wpf user forums / groups

Tags: wpf, silverlight, forum

The only forums I know of are:
  - [WPF Disciples](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples?lnk=srg&hl=en); this is a great group because the um, disciples *are* experts but seems like 1/2 the posts are 'inside' comments between the um, disciples. By design, it is for mere mortals to observe only.
  - [WPF on Codeplex](http://wpf.codeplex.com/); useful but usually only by way of catching a new release of something. Discussion threads of interest are not easily located and it doesn't seem as though response from knowledgeable responders comes often or timely.
  -  [MSFT forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/753c2a0b-753f-43d3-afb3-01d4d3c93787); noisy and confusing. More often than not an answer is repeated randomly and doesn't address the question.

So I typically use SO as my first option to find an answer to a WPF type of issue. Where do you go online when you hit a WPF snag?

Just to be clear I mean by forums are places like SO where you can ask a question and get a response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forums on http://www.windowsclient.net is another good place where you can ask questions.

A great idea is to follow the WPF gurus/experts on twitter and then put your (short) questions across to them. Of course, there is no guarantee that they *will* answer, after all they lead busy lives too, but quite often they do.

Answer (score 0):

Google. Google index all the forums you listed as well as blogs. Many times I find answers in some blog that Google directs me to.

Answer (score 0):

I'll search in google with by question with suffix of stack overflow or msdn. Tada I'm done. :)